# How to get log file deletion to work with spring-boot-starter-log4j2?

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, slf4j

My project uses Slf4j version 1.7.25 and spring-boot-starter-log4j2 v1.5.21.RELEASE. I have configured a log4j2.xml file with Delete action. The delete doesn't seem to work at all. I have tried to add

```
<configuration status="trace">
```

But it doesn't show any error logs pertaining to paths.

Here is the log output:

```
2019-05-25 18:41:20,124 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=Delete, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.action.DeleteAction].
2019-05-25 18:41:20,124 main DEBUG createDeleteAction(basePath="/logs/hadoop/archive/", followLinks="false", maxDepth="2", testMode="false", PathSorter=null, ={IfAll[IfFileName(glob:okie-*.log.gz), IfLastModified(age=P1D)]}, ScriptCondition=null, Configuration(okieLog4j2Config))
2019-05-25 18:41:20,124 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=DefaultRolloverStrategy, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.DefaultRolloverStrategy].
2019-05-25 18:41:20,125 main DEBUG createStrategy(max="1", min="null", fileIndex="null", compressionLevel="null", ={DeleteAction[basePath=/logs/hadoop/archive, options=[], maxDepth=2, conditions=[IfAll[IfFileName(glob:okie-*.log.gz), IfLastModified(age=P1D)]]]}, stopCustomActionsOnError="true", Configuration(okieLog4j2Config))
```

Also please take a look at my config xml file below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="okieLog4j2Config" status="trace"
  strict="true" monitorInterval="5">
  <properties>
    <property name="patternlayout">%d [%t] %-5level %logger{36} -
      %msg%n%throwable{full}
    </property>
  </properties>
  <appenders>
    <appender name="Console" type="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${patternlayout}"/>
    </appender>
    <Routing name="File">
      <Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTING_KEY}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="okie.log" bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true"
            fileName="logs/${ctx:ROUTING_KEY}/okie.log"
            filePattern="logs/${ctx:ROUTING_KEY}/archive/$${date:yyyy-MM}/okie-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %p %c %L - %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
              <!--<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>-->
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1">
              <Delete basePath="/logs/hadoop/archive/" maxDepth="2">
                <IfAll>
                  <IfFileName glob="okie-*.log.gz"/>
                  <IfLastModified age="1d"/>
                </IfAll>
              </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
  </appenders>
  <loggers>
    <Logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
    <root level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="Console" level="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="File" level="WARN"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

The Log files are getting generated as intended with appropriate name which is provided during run time and the rolling is also working. Only deletion is not happening.

Also, please let me know if I have to add anymore information.

**UPDATE SOLUTION:**

The "/" forward slash was the problem in the paths that I had mentioned for deletion. Removing it fixed it. But I still wonder why it did not show up in the logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a small application to try using Delete action. So far it is working for me.

Please see the example at https://github.com/bigzidane/spring-boot-delete-log. Check the READMe.md to see how the previous logs got deleted.

Please enable TRACE in your log4j configuration (`<Configuration status="TRACE" monitorInterval="30">`), it will help you detect why the Delete action is not working for you by just following logs which you see in my README.md file.

It may come from the path you are settings are wrong (Maybe I'm not correct here) but with TRACE option I believe you can find out information by yourself.

Logs with Trace option example

```
2019-05-25 09:38:33.756 INFO WINDOWS-ESDA5FC --- [ main] c.e.SpringBootDeleteLogApp : Starting SpringBootDeleteLogApp on WINDOWS-ESDA5FC with PID 17236 (C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-delete-log\target\classes started by dotha in C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-delete-log)

2019-05-25 09:38:33.760 INFO WINDOWS-ESDA5FC --- [ main] c.e.SpringBootDeleteLogApp : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2019-05-25 09:38:33.798 INFO WINDOWS-ESDA5FC --- [ main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@338fc1d8: startup date [Sat May 25 09:38:33 CDT 2019]; root of context hierarchy

2019-05-25 09:38:33,802 main TRACE DefaultRolloverStrategy.purge() took 3.0 milliseconds

2019-05-25 09:38:33,804 main DEBUG RollingFileManager executing synchronous FileRenameAction[logs\log4j2-demo.log to logs\log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log, renameEmptyFiles=false]

2019-05-25 09:38:33,805 main TRACE Renamed file C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-delete-log\logs\log4j2-demo.log to C:\Users\dotha\IdeaProjects\spring-boot-delete-log\logs\log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log with Files.move

2019-05-25 09:38:33,806 main DEBUG RollingFileManager executing async CompositeAction[DeleteAction[basePath=logs, options=[], maxDepth=1, conditions=[IfFileName(glob:log4j2-demo-*.log), IfLastModified(age=PT1M)]]]

2019-05-25 09:38:33,806 main DEBUG Now writing to logs/log4j2-demo.log at 2019-05-25T09:38:33.806-0500

2019-05-25 09:38:33,807 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 DEBUG Starting DeleteAction[basePath=logs, options=[], maxDepth=1, conditions=[IfFileName(glob:log4j2-demo-*.log), IfLastModified(age=PT1M)]]

2019-05-25 09:38:33,809 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 DEBUG DeleteAction complete in 0.001881032 seconds

2019-05-25 09:38:33,810 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE Sorted paths:

2019-05-25 09:38:33,810 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE logs\log4j2-demo.log (modified: 2019-05-25T14:38:33.807885Z)

2019-05-25 09:38:33,812 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE logs\log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log (modified: 2019-05-25T14:38:33.803895Z)

2019-05-25 09:38:33,812 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE logs\log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-1.log (modified: 2019-05-25T14:36:13.862034Z)

2019-05-25 09:38:33,812 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE IfFileName REJECTED: 'glob:log4j2-demo-*.log' does not match relative path 'log4j2-demo.log'

2019-05-25 09:38:33,812 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE Not deleting base=logs, relative=log4j2-demo.log

2019-05-25 09:38:33,812 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE IfFileName ACCEPTED: 'glob:log4j2-demo-*.log' matches relative path 'log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log'

2019-05-25 09:38:33,813 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE IfLastModified REJECTED: log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log ageMillis '9' < 'PT1M'

2019-05-25 09:38:33,813 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE Not deleting base=logs, relative=log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-2.log

2019-05-25 09:38:33,813 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE IfFileName ACCEPTED: 'glob:log4j2-demo-*.log' matches relative path 'log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-1.log'

2019-05-25 09:38:33,813 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE IfLastModified ACCEPTED: log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-1.log ageMillis '139951' >= 'PT1M'

**2019-05-25 09:38:33,813 Log4j2-TF-2-RollingFileManager-3 TRACE Deleting logs\log4j2-demo-2019-05-25-1.log**
```

Good luck,

Comment: Thanks for all your effort and suggestions. This was helpful, I was able to resolve my issue.

Comment: Great to know it helped you. Pls update what your finding so ppl can learn from it.